# JS: nested function v prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object in Javascript and want to process the data passed into the constructor using a function that could later be called externally with more data.  Naturally I don't want to duplicate the code (once in the constructor, once in a function), so how should I best set this up?

I could use a nested function, but I'm told this is inefficient:

```
function MyOb(data) {
    this.myData = {};
    function addData(newData) {
        //Add newData to myData
    }
    addData(data);
}
```

But if I use a prototype I get a "can't find variable addData" error on line 3:

```
function MyOb(data) {
    this.myData = {};
    addData(data);
}

MyOb.prototype.addData = function(newData) {
        //Add newData to myData
}
```

So am I forced to either use a nested function or repeat myself, or is there a way of making this work using prototype?

Comment: With your code `myData` is common to all instances of `myObj`. Is this  the intention? If `myData` can be a property then things are simpler.

Comment: Yep!  It's a generic property store with get, set, save, load functions that has multiple instansiations by different parts of a larger application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
function MyOb(data) {
    var myData;
    addData(data);
}
```

to

```
function MyOb(data) {
    this.myData = {}; // or another initialization
    this.addData(data);
}
```

You need the explicit `this` in JavaScript objects.

Note also that using `var myData` makes it private : you won't be able to use this variable from functions defined outside the constructor, including the `addData` function. That's why you probably need `this.myData` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using the prototype you need to create a new object:

```
var abc = new MyOb(data);
```

then you can access the function using the `this`:

```
function MyOb(data) {
    var _myData; // local variable in this scope (addData won't have access)
    this.myData = {}; // public variable
    this.addData(data);
}
```

If you don't use the `new`to build your object, then the `this`will be the `window`, and your code won't work

Answer (score 1):

You should just make the nested function publically available as a property on your object:

```
function MyOb(data) {
    var myData;
    function addData(newData) {
        //Add newData to myData
    }
    addData(data);
    this.addData = addData;
}
```

Your current code with the prototype suffers from the problem that you're trying to get the function like a variable, while it's a (inherited) property of your instance (referenced by [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)). However, changing it to

```
    this.addData(data);
```

would lead to the error `can't find variable myData` in the prototype function - it's a variable that is local to the constructor. You would have to make that a instance property as well to use the prototype. See also [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572).

Comment: Thanks I've updated code in the question.  Thanks for the link too.

Comment: Well, if it's a property anyway then you just have to call the prototype method with the `this.addData(data);`. If you need the full function code, look at dystroy's answer, I'm not gonna repeat it :-)